# How can I parse multiple XML file data using mapreduce?

Tags: hadoop, xml-parsing, mapreduce, hdfs

I want to parse multiple XML files having structure as follows:

```
<parent tag property1='p1' xmlns:'sm link'>
<Tag 1> tag 1 value </Tag 1>
<Tag 2> tag 2 value </Tag 2>
<Tag 3>
<Tag 3.1> tag 3.1 value </Tag 3.1>
</Tag 3>
</parent tag>
```

I want to write an Map Reduce code and dump the parsed data into HDFS (Hadoop 1.0).
Also how to how to pass multiple flies at one instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mahaout's `XmlInputFormat` for reading XML data.

And in driver class set these configuration settings.

```
conf.set("xmlinput.start","<root")` 
conf.set("xmlinput.end", "</root>");
job.setInputFormatClass(XmlInputFormat.class);
```

Download mahaout's jar file.

Treat each file as a string, and do the processing.

For running multiple files as input, put all files in a folder and give input path as folder path.

Comment: Consider updating your answer with appropriate links.